# Will Turning Data usage off disable the hotspot?

Tags: iphone, wifi, tethering

Without going into to much detail of why I’m asking .... if I turn off the data usage of one persons iPhone will that essentially disable their ability to be the “hot spot” for someone else to connect to... Even if they are connected to WiFi...

Person one has WiFi access and data and the ability to be a WiFi hotspot.

Person 2 doesn’t have any of that so they connect to person 1 to leach off their data plan.

If I turn off the data plan for person one they can still connect to WiFi. Can the hotspot be used by person 2 if no data plan is active for person 1? Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes.If you turn off the data plan, then regardless if they try to be a hotspot, it won’t matter because there won’t be a data plan to use.

However, (I know this because I was researching data plans last week) you can get a data plan that doesn’t have hot spot or tethering capability.  So, your user can still have mobile data, but they won’t be able to use their mobile device as a hotspot.   You also might want to ask the carrier if they can manually turn off the hotspot function.

Comment: Ok thank you! And I’ll check with ATT and see what can be done. Thank you again!